# ES6 way - Get unique values from a nested array by key

Tags: javascript, sorting, filtering

trying to improve my JS chops.

Is there a cleaner way to retrieve the property value from the array below, by key, from a nested object, removing duplicates and sorting them alphabetically?

Here's what I have:

```
getObjectValues(array, key){

      var unique = [];
      
      array.forEach(function(item){
        item[key].forEach(function(value){
          if (unique.indexOf(value) < 0) {
            unique.push(value)
          }
        })
      });

      return unique.sort();
    },
```

example array of object:

```
[
  { name: 'hello', value: ['a','b','c']},
  { name: 'hello', value: ['a','b','c']},
  { name: 'hello', value: ['a','b','c']}
]
```

expected output should be an array:

```
var array = ['a','b','c']
```

Comment: whta does not work?

Comment: Probably the uniqueness and sorting, since the "value" are arrays.

Comment: So your input is the `list`, and the `key` you'd pass would be `'value'`?

Comment: Those `0:`, `1:`, `3:` don't make it look like a valid array.

Comment: @Bergi Yes that's correct, let me update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need something concise, you may go as simple as that:

- make use of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get rid of duplicates
- employ [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (with slight touch of [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)) to extract `value` items from within all objects into single array

```js
const src = [{name:'hello',value:['c','b','d']},{name:'hello',value:['e','b','c']},{name:'hello',value:['f','a','e']}],

      result = [...new Set(src.flatMap(({value}) => value))].sort()

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

If you need something really fast, you may do the following:

- use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to turn your array into `Set` of unique records (looping through `value` items with [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and doing [`Set.prototype.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add))
- spread resulting `Set` into array and `.sort()` that

```js
const src = [{name:'hello',value:['c','b','d']},{name:'hello',value:['e','b','c']},{name:'hello',value:['f','a','e']}],

      result = [...src.reduce((acc,{value}) => 
        (value.forEach(acc.add, acc), acc), new Set())].sort()

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{Min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: If you need something fast, you shouldn't use `flatMap` either, especially if you anticipate many duplicates. And never, ever use `console.log` inside a benchmark!

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a Set, and add all the items to it:

```js
let arr = [
  { name: 'hello', value: ['a','b','c']},
  { name: 'hello', value: ['a','b','c']},
  { name: 'hello', value: ['a','b','c']}
]

console.log(
    Array.from(
        new Set(
            arr.reduce(
                (carry, current) => [...carry, ...current.value],
                 []
            )
        )
    ).sort()
)
```

Comment: Spread syntax used for pushing items into array affects performance in a negative way.

Comment: The `.sort` disagrees with you